# Asus R9 270x mining 24/7 setup

Tags: mining-hardware, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I'm using [Asus R9270X-DC2T-2GD5](http://www.asus.com/us/Graphics_Cards/R9270XDC2T2GD5/) for mining and the temps remain stable at 68C or below even with 99% GPU load for hours.

Stock cooling with my Cooler Master CM 690 II case with positive air flow. I can move the case to a more ventilated area or just take of the side panel for greater airflow.

- What are the ideal config params for this specific card?
- Do the temperature readings look Ok?
- Do I need to do anything more in terms of cooling or tuning the card (its already factory overclocked)?
- Is mining going to make the card fail early? If so, any idea how early? I'm OK if this cards lasts 2-3 years as opposed to 4-5 years.

Comment: Are you mining Bitcoins? If so, I'm afraid you are out of luck. That GPU Mining train passed a long time ago. Try Litecoin.

Comment: Yeah, was afraid so. Thanks for the alternative! But what about rest of the questions?

Comment: I can't answer those unfortunately. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.